# Green grass streaks over septic tank field

Tags: septic

I've noticed in my yard where the septic tank is that there are two rows of green streaks of grass going in a single direction for about 20 yards or so.

Is this a sign for concern or normal for a septic field?

Thanks for any advice on this issue.

– Mike

Comment: This area is getting more moisture and organic fertilization than the rest of the lawn.   Water and fertilize the rest if you want it to match.

Comment: it could just be that the pack around the pipe makes for better soil drainage, which encourages grass roots to go deeper into the soil to get water, which means that grass will be better at getting moisture all the time, which means it will appear more verdant than surrounding grass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erma Bombeck, humorist who wrote several very funny books, one was entitled: "The grass  is always greener over the septic tank". So unless you have surfacing effluent, bad odors, floating grass, just consider it free fertilizer.

Answer (score 1):

Drainfields work both ways: effluent “leaks” down into the soil, but it also evaporates up into the air (that’s why the septic designer establishes the height of the drainfield pipe.)

Btw, the pipe is half solid and half perforated. It’s laid “flat” with the perforated holes up...so the effluent will flow to the ends of all the pipes and not just empty in the first few feet of the system. That’s why you see so much of the length of the drainfield pipes and not just the first few feet.

Comment: All of the videos I've seen about leach fields have the holes down.